# Dispatcher.Invoke with Action delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to use `Action<string, bool>` type of delegate to invoke the `Dispatcher.Invoke`

**Named method to use with detegate**

```
private void SomeMethod(string name,out bool result)
{
    ...
}
```

When I used the following it gives an error says not matching to signature.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<string, bool>(SomeMethod),new Object[2]{name, result});
```

What is the wrong I am doing here. Please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action<,>` doesn't have an `out` parameter. You'd need to use your own delegate, like this:

```
public void ActionOut<T1, T2>(T1 input, out T2 output)
```

That *might* work (in terms of not throwing an exception) - I'm sure it would with reflection; I'm not so sure about with `Dispatcher.Invoke`. It *won't* leave the result value in your `result` variable though - it will leave it in the array, which you're then ignoring. You'd want:

```
object[] args = new object[] { name, null };
Dispatcher.Invoke(new ActionOut<string, bool>(SomeMethod), args);
result = (bool) args[1];
```

But it would be better to just make the method *return* the result, and use a `Func<string, bool>` instead. You should almost *never* use an `out` parameter in a method which returns `void`. To my mind, `out` parameters are effectively designed to let you return more than one value - if you only want to return one value, use the return type!

Comment: Ok. I understood what is the wrong that I am trying to do.Your answer completely address my issue. I will use `Func<string, bool>`. Thanks for the answer.